# John, Adam and 8 more people are standing in a row in random order. What is the probability that between John and Adam are exactly 5 people?

Tags: probability

I figure theres 9 possible scenarios, tha either 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 people are between them. How do I calculate the probability its exactly 5?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: **Strategy:** Choose two spots for John and Adam, arrange them in those spots, then arrange the other eight people in the remaining spots.  The constraint that there five people between John and Adam limits the number of ways they can be placed in the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nine possible scenarios are not equally likely. For instance, if there are eight people between them, then they must occupy positions $1$ and $10$. But if there are no people between them, they can occupy positions $1$ and $2$, or positions $2$ and $3$, etc; so this is nine times more likely.

Think of all possible pairs of positions $(J,A)$ for John and Adam. There are $90$ such pairs, and they are all equally likely. How many such pairs satisfy $|J-A|=6$ ?